# how to make text in centre vertically

Tags: html, css

I have to display some text contents in center (both horizontally and vertically )with some background color.

I have this code

```
"<h2 style="text-align:center; height:40px; background-color:#ABCDEF; color:#FFFCBA;"><span style="margin:auto;">USER LOGIN</span></h2>"
```

This making the text display in center horizontally but not vertically.

Any help will be great!

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean to have the " " around hour html?

Comment: this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: Use padding instead of height on the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use padding, take the height off

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; background-color:#ABCDEF; color:#FFFCBA;padding:20px;">
    <span style="margin:auto;">USER LOGIN</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <h2 style="position:absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%;">Your text</h2> 
</div>
```

Comment: I would't think making the div 100% 100% is a good idea....

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
h2{
  text-align:center; 
  background-color:#ABCDEF;
  color:#FFFCBA;
  height:40px;
}

span{
  line-height:40px;
}
```

MARKUP:

```
<h2 ><span>USER LOGIN</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>center</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Get the height and width of the screen using 100vh

Comment: I like the part you provided information about getting the height and width